# LAS to Old Format USGS 7.5 DEM

Tags: dem, las

I'm trying to use an old software that only imports the old style USGS DEM info.  I've found somewhere to download an entire quadrant of which I need about 1 percent.  I have a current LAS file of the area I want.  Is there any way to convert it back to the old style DEM point file format?

Comment: Please refresh my memory... what is the "old style" data?  It would really help if you posted the download link.